# Homemade Du Nüoy ring?

Tags: surface-tension

I am helping my daughter work on her science project.  She wants to test the surface tension of various solutions.

I bought a [cheap tensiometer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09VGC7SDS) off of Amazon and now I need the Du Nüoy ring to attach to it.  But no one sells these.  They just sell a whole Surface Tension Tensiometer device for a lot of money.

Any advice on how I can make something like this that will still work for the experiment?  (Meaning it will still draw up the liquid until it tears the surface membrane.)

For clarity, here is a picture of what I need from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_No%C3%BCy_ring_method):

[image: Du Nüoy Ring]